# If I set some heavy layouts to null does it cause garbage collection soon?

Tags: android

My android app contains some images for list backgrounds and other stuff ( images have size between 2KB and 20KB), I need to put six layouts, at one time only one is  visible (4 of them contains two expandable listviews) in one activity. Lists are not very long, around 10 items each. When I start and after some time go to another actvity (from this heavy go to new without finish) I got OutOfMemory exception. When I build my app it is only around 2.5 MB.
I have lot of setBackground functions and 5 ViewPagers. If I set some layouts to null does it cause garbage collection soon ? Did anyone have similar problem whwn dealing with lot of images inside app ?

Comment: Garbage collection will happen when it happens! If you set some layouts to null, more memory will be cleared when GC happens. Also you could `recycle` images after you don't need them anymore..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when you set the backgrounds you are just calling setBackground(...)

I suggest you load the bitmaps according to this [example](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap).

something along the lines of: `setBackground(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource());`

It is bad practice but you can always call `System.gc();` to throttle/force a GC when you've release a resource.